# How to remove single quote from a list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list like this

```
res = ['-14.82381293', '-0.29423447', '-13.56067979', '-1.6288903']
```

I want to remove the single quotes ''. How can i achieve this on python.

I tried

```
res = [item.replace("'", '') for item in res]
print(res)
```

but it didn't work. any idea how?

Comment: Its because your array is storing those numbers as strings. You can convert those elems to floating numbers and then to  a numpy array. But what is the point?

Comment: I misinterpreted your question at the first instance , but you can try this: `res = [float(item) for item in res]` or `list(map(float, res))`

Comment: @PKumar thank you. this seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the elements are stored as strings in the list `res`.
You have to convert those elements into numbers.

In this situation python's builtin `map(...)` function can be used.
Syntax of map:

```py
variable_to_store_new_value = map(type, list_of_elements)
```

Above code will return a map object. Convert that into a list.

```py
variable = list(map(type, list_of_elements))
```

Here type can be any valid python data type (str, int, float, etc.) or a function.

### Solution to your problem

```py
res = list(map(float, res))
```

Answer (score 1):

what says float about it?

```
res = [float(item) for item in res]
print(res)
```

honestly, have not seen the answer in comments

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are coming because the numbers are stored as string data type.

Therefore to remove the quotes, you must convert them into float.

```
res = ['-14.82381293', '-0.29423447', '-13.56067979', '-1.6288903']
new_res=[]
for i in range(0,len(res)):
    new_res.append(float(res[i]))
print(new_res)
```

You can do this .

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
res = ['-14.82381293', '-0.29423447', '-13.56067979', '-1.6288903']
res=map(str, res)
print ('[%s]' % ','.join(map(str, res)))
```

This code is used for string or Integer or a decimal number
for example:

```
res = ['-14.82381293', '-0.29423447', '-13.56067979', '-1.6288903','book','3234']
```